# What to do when a question gets an answer off-site?

Tags: discussion, answers

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25178756/caught-between-nosuchdirectoryexception-and-indexnotfoundexception/29525531) in the close votes queue. It piqued my curiosity, and researching it, I found that the OP (I assume that I'm safe assuming paddymcc is the same person as Paddy McCann) had posted on the Islandora Google Group forum as well, where the issue had been resolved.

It's pretty niche, but seems a valuable question. In the interest of being a self-contained resource, I did my best to provide a (community wiki) answer to the question based on their resolution there, and followed up with a quote from it.

I'm not sure if I did the right thing though. Should I have just commented, linking to the Google Groups thread, and asked the OP to answer? Or should I have just given a brief summary answer, and nixed the quotation and citation tomfoolery?

Comment: Those all seem like decent options.  Personally, I would post a "real" answer if I did any summarizing, explaining etc.  Otherwise I like the community wiki option.  I don't think that commenting the user is consistent enough to rely on (what if the user is no longer active?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you did the right thing by providing a summary answer. If the question had already been closed, I think it would be ok to leave the link in a comment. Stack Overflow tends to rank pretty high in search queries, and it's better to not make people chase down an answer by leaving just a link (whether it's in a comment or an answer) if you can provide a full answer.